# Microsoft Graph throws Request_ResourceNotFound instead of null/0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm an apprentice with 4 months of experience and I got a task to build a holiday request application using data from Microsoft Graph. One of the functions of app is to look up a user'ss manager and display it on the dashboard. Everything was going smooth until my boss logged in. After running Microsoft Graph Query To find out current user Manager, Graph Api returns and error`(Request_ResourceNotFound)` and breaks whole application instead of returning null or 0. I don't know how to handle that error.

I have tried to return `null` if the result is `null`, but that didn't do anything.

This what my controller expects:

```
var allUsersConnectedToCurrentManagerDisplayName = graphHelper.GetManagerForCurrentUser(userIdToCheck).DisplayName;
var allUsersConnectedToCurrentManagerEmail = graphHelper.GetManagerForCurrentUser(userIdToCheck).UserPrincipalName;
var allUsersConnectedToCurrentManagerId = graphHelper.GetManagerForCurrentUser(userIdToCheck).Id;
```

Microsoft Graph Helper:

```
User GetDirectManagerForUser(GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient, string managerId)
{

    using(var task = Task.Run(async() => await _graphServiceClient.Users[managerId].Manager.Request().GetAsync()))
    {
        while (!task.IsCompleted)
            Thread.Sleep(200);

        var manager = task.Result as Microsoft.Graph.User;

        return manager;
    }
}
```

I was expecting this to return null and just don't display a direct manager for the user without anyone above him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you've got a few things going on here.

The first, and the most glaring, issue is that your code is requesting the same User record from Graph three times in a row. Each call you're making to `GetDirectManagerForUser` is downloading the entire User profile. You want to avoid doing this:

```cs
var manager = await graphHelper.GetManagerForCurrentUser(userIdToCheck);
var allUsersConnectedToCurrentManagerDisplayName = manager.DisplayName;
var allUsersConnectedToCurrentManagerEmail = manager.UserPrincipalName;
var allUsersConnectedToCurrentManagerId = manager.Id;
```

The second issue to avoid is wrapping your request in a Task like that. It adds a lot of complexity to the code, makes it super hard to debug, and isn't necessary. Simply add `async Task<>` at the method level and let the compiler handle wiring it up for you:

```cs
async Task<User> GetDirectManagerForUser(GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient, string managerId)
```

Third, your casting the result but not capturing any exceptions (i.e. the `404` your getting). You want to capture these and return an empty User:

```cs
var manager = await graphHelper.GetManagerForCurrentUser(userIdToCheck);
var allUsersConnectedToCurrentManagerDisplayName = manager.DisplayName;
var allUsersConnectedToCurrentManagerEmail = manager.UserPrincipalName;
var allUsersConnectedToCurrentManagerId = manager.Id;

async Task<User> GetDirectManagerForUser(GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient, string managerId)
{
    try
    {
        // Normal path
        return await _graphServiceClient
            .Users[managerId]
            .Manager
            .Request()
            .GetAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // Something went wrong or no manager exists
        var emptyUser = new User();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to catch the exception in order to return null.
I would write the function like this:

```
    public User GetDirectManagerForUser(GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient, string managerId)
    {
        //.Result, because this function in synchronious
        try 
        {       
            var manager = await _graphServiceClient.Users[managerId].Manager.Request().GetAsync().Result;
            return manager;
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

You could also make the function async like this:

```
    public async Task<User> GetDirectManagerForUser(GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient, string managerId)
    {

        try 
        {       
            var manager = await _graphServiceClient.Users[managerId].Manager.Request().GetAsync();
            return manager;
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Why haven't you specified an [accessibility level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/accessibility-levels)?